# Number of ways to a sum using 2 numbers

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I need to find a the number of ways to a sum (say 1000000) using only numbers 1 and 2. Order matters. I made a solution using combinations:

[image]

Where `n` is the sum.

Example:

For `n=7`, there are `21` ways.

1111111, 111112, 111121, 111211, 112111, 121111, 211111, 11122....1222, 2122, 2212, 2221

The number can be very large, and I have to find it modulo some large prime number. (yes its a little sub-problem of an online coding competition).
I need a more computer friendly formula..any help please?
Or maybe can it be done by creating a recurrence and matrix exponentiation?

Comment: If it's an online coding competition, how does getting someone else to solve it demonstrate your coding ability? Sorry, no help here.

Comment: Here's a hint: To get the sum of `n`, you either select a `1` and get the sum of `n-1` or you select a `2` and get the sum of `n-2`. Does that recursion remind you of anything?

Comment: Another hint: compute the values for `n=1` up to `n=6`, say.  Notice anything suspicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways of doing this is equal to the nth Fibonacci number, F(n), easy to calculate.

Proof by induction. Assume true for n. Consider a sequence of length n+1. This can be formed by adding a 1 to a sequence of total n, or 2 to a sequence of total n-1. This are distinct and represent all possibilities.

So F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)
F(1) = 1

Neat, huh?

Answer (score 1):

The number you are trying to find is the nth Fibonacci number.
Best way (since ur saying n can be really large) is to implemet this recursive `O(log n)` formula (these are 2x2 matrices, sorry for the ugly format).

```
[F(n+2)] = [1 1] [F(k+1)]
[F(n+1)]   [1 0] [F (k) ]
```

Maybe the explicit form will suit you better, instead of the recursive one:

```
[1 1]^n = [F(k+1)   F(k) ]
[1 0]     [ F(k)   F(k-1)]
```

It is the fastest way know to me to compute a Fibonacci number.
Keep in mind the output grows really quickly, so you wont be able to cache the results for large n.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
def onesAndTwos(num):
    if num <= 0:
        return set()
    elif num == 1:
        return set([(1, 0)])
    elif num == 2:
        return set([(2,0), (0, 1)])
    else:
        setA = set([(1 + x[0], x[1]) for x in onesAndTwos(num-1)])
        setB = set([(x[0], 1 + x[1]) for x in onesAndTwos(num-2)])
        setA.update(setB);
        return setA

print onesAndTwos(10)
print len(onesAndTwos(10))
```

It uses a set of tuples where the first element is the number of ones and the second the number of twos. So a sum of 3 can be produced with `set[(3,0), (1,1)]`. To find how many combinations there are you can count the tuples in the set. The output for 10:

```
set([(8, 1), (6, 2), (0, 5), (4, 3), (10, 0), (2, 4)])
6
```

This is somewhat of a dynamic programming approach where we have a set of recurring subproblems and a similar structure throughout, allowing us to build on previous solutions. And this isn't optimal because you are not reusing previously calculated values in the two branches (the first when taking away 1, and the second when taking away 2), so I'd consider this a naive solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static int magic(int input) {
        if (input == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (input == 2) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return magic(input-1) + magic(input-2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int input = 7;
        int numberOfCombinations = magic(input);
        System.out.println("The total number of combinations for the given integer "+input+" is "+numberOfCombinations);
    }
}
```

Complete and working Java code. Feel free to use it for your competition. I hope the code is self-explanatory of the underlying algorithm. Good luck!